# What is the best practice to store paths in a geolocation app?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, geolocation

I'm making an app for public transport geolocation. I want to store all the bus and tram routes in the mobile phone, to be able to check it in an offline mode. I have thought about 2 possible solutions:

1) The one I'm using right now. For each route, I have pairs of coordinates for each point I want to draw in the road in the map, for example:

19.893169,50.054337

19.893169,50.054340

19.893290,50.053871

19.893259,50.053730
....

I have this stored as "100.kml" in the assets directory. So when I want to show the route for the bus 100, I just go and parse this information from the asset file 100.kml.

So in this solution, I would have as many files as routes, and the average weight is 2-3 kb.

2) The second solution is to prepopulate a database with all this points, also the points for the stops, etc... Something I'm not sure if will be worthy, or it will take more time to be constantly consulting the database to draw all the points.

I don't know if it would be a bad practice to solve it like in the solution number one. I mean, I would have a lot of files in the asset folder, 200 of 2-3 kb each, so lets say it would take more or less 500kb.

Any thoughts about what would be better?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you interested in the route itself or only the stops, say, a bus passes by?

Comment: I'm interested in both, I draw the line of the route itself (with all this coordinates) and I want to put points for each stop.

Answer (score 3):

A SQLite database would definitely be better. If you know your points before hand, you can create a .sql script that runs at the start of your application when your database is created to populate all your entries.

A database will help you better organize your data, and easily query the set of points you need.